# Casting float to string without scientific notation

Tags: python, string, casting, double, scientific-notation

The float:

```
fl = 0.000005
```

casts to `String` as `str(fl)=='5e-06'`. however, I want it to cast as `str(fl)='0.000005'` for exporting to `CSV` purposes.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to use `str()` or can you do something like `'{:f}'.format(fl)`?

Comment: as grc has said `"{:f}".format(fl)` will do what you want

Comment: @PadraicCunningham @grc I get exception `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: zero length field name in format
`

Comment: what version of python? Does `"{0:f}".format(fl)` work?

Comment: Perhaps `'{0:.16f}'.format(fl).rstrip('0')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the standard string formatting option stating the precision you want

```
>>> fl = 0.000005
>>> print '%.6f' % fl
0.000005
```

Comment: What if I just want it to the exact accuracy as I specified `fl` with. So if I set `fl = 0.00214`, I want `string = '0.00214'`, or if I set `fl = 0.0000000006`, I want `string = '0.0000000006'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
fl = 0.00005
s = '%8.5f' % fl
print s, type(s)
```

Gives

```
0.00005 <type 'str'>
```

In case you want no extra digits, use %g (although it uses exponential notation for e.g. 0.000005). See for example:

```
fl = 0.0005
s = '%g' % fl
print s, type(s)

fl = 0.005
s = '%g' % fl
print s, type(s)
```

Gives

```
0.0005 <type 'str'>
0.005 <type 'str'>
```

Comment: `%g` will give scientific notation for numbers like 0.000005. BTW your `str` calls are not needed.

Comment: @interjay thanks for the comment, I updated my answer accordingly.